# Capturar el valor de un Input en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un input en mi html y quiero que lo que escriba en él se pueda capturar en alguna variable , para luego hacer un usuario con JS , alguna idea?

Comment: recuerda ingresar tu código js y html para que la comunidad pueda darte una solución adecuada

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask], aquí encontraras algunos consejos para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Uno de los más recomendados es incluir un [mcve], esto ayudará a que otros usuarios puedan ayudarte. Puedes agregar esto haciendo clic en [edit]. También te invto a realizar el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te refieres a algo como esto?

```js
 const getValueInput = () =>{
      let inputValue = document.getElementById("domTextElement").value; 
      document.getElementById("valueInput").innerHTML = inputValue; 
      }

function myFunction() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("domTextElement").value; 
   var x = document.getElementById("valueInput").innerHTML = inputValue; 
  alert (x);
}
```

```html
<label for="domTextElement">Escribe algo aqui: </label>
  <input type="text" id="domTextElement" onkeyup="getValueInput()"> 
  
  <button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()"> 
     Muestrame que escribi 
  </button> 
  
  <p id="valueInput"></p>
```

Comment: Si , eso queria hacer , muchisimas gracias enserio!